# How to metaClass a Groovy method that takes a closure?

Tags: groovy, metaclass

How would one metaClass a method that takes an object(s) and a closure?

Specifically say,

```
public void eachRow(GString gstring, Closure closure)
```

I'd like to metaClass eachRow() such that it prints the gstring parameter, and ignores the Closure. The goal is to create an app, that when passed a certain parameter does a sort of 'dry run' execution using groovy.sql.Sql, where instead of executing the queries, it just prints the statements it would have normally executed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So I think my issue wasn't how I was defining the method, but what I was (or wasn't returning).  This appears to work ...

```
sql.metaClass.eachRow = { String qry, Closure c ->
    println qry
    new GroovyRowResult([:]) // I was returning null, adding this fixed me.
}
```